# A strange error when trying to scanf into a global int

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, scanf

Here is the code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <clocale>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>  

using namespace std;

int souls;

void userInput(char situation[20]) {
    if (situation == "souls") {
        scanf("%i", souls);
        printf("%i", souls);
    }
}

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");

    userInput("souls");

    system("pause");
}
```

It brakes after I input something in my `scanf()` (trying to change a global `int`) via the console (int number for example) and drops me into an "unhandled exception"

[image]

Why is it so? I am using MS Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: #offtopic: How do you distinguish between "strange" and "not strange" errors?

Comment: @EugeneSh. "strange" -> runtime fail. "non-strange" -> compilation error. Just my two cents. :)

Comment: `if (situation=="souls")` compares the string *locations* not their content. It will only be true if the compiler is configured to share, instead of duplicate, equal string literals.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the code would even compile:  `#include <string>`  This is not the correct header -- it should be `#include <cstring>`.  The `string` header is for `std::string`, something you should be using instead of char arrays.

Comment: `I am using MS Visual Studio 2005` Why? It's year 2016 already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several issues:

- You cannot compare C strings this way: `if (situation == "souls")`: you are comparing the addresses of the `char` arrays, not their contents. You need to use `strcmp` (and include `<cstring>`) for this:

  ```
  if (!strcmp(situation, "souls"))
  ```
- The signature `void userInput(char situation[20])` is confusing: the size `20` information is ignored and your are actually passing the address of a shorter string literal, this signature would be more appropriate:

  ```
  void userInput(const char *situation)
  ```
- You need to pass the address of the output variable to `scanf` and check the return value: `scanf("%i", souls);` invokes undefined behavior, it should be changed to:

  ```
  if (scanf("%i", &souls) == 1) {
      /* souls was assigned a value */
  } else {
      /* scanf failed to parse an integer */
  }
  ```
- The signature for `main` should not be `void main()`, it should be either:

  ```
  int main()
  ```

  or

  ```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  ```

Comment: I always thought what you refer to as a *"prototype"* is called a function's *"signature"* -- is this incorrect?

Comment: Also, I thought `main`'s type is inserted by the C++ compiler so it's not needed at all (but still not  `void`)?

Comment: @cat: *prototype* is the C terminology, I rephrased the answer.

Comment: @chqrlie Even though my comment stated this, maybe you can add that the proper header file for C-string handling is `<cstring>` and not `<string>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: You are correct, I added extra precisions.  The OP is not writing real C++ code yet.

Answer (score 4):

In your code

```
scanf("%i", souls);
```

should be

```
scanf("%i", &souls);
            ^
```

[`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) needs a pointer to type as the argument to store the scanned value corresponding to the supplied format specifier.

That said, `if (situation=="souls")` is wrong, too. You cannot compare the contents of strings using the `==` operator. You need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) for that.

Comment: The *reason* behind this is because `scanf`` needs a pointer to a var so it can modify it in place. OP might not know this; perhaps you should explain in your answer?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I changed the function to 
void userInput(int situation) { 
if (situation==1) ....

and added the & symbol - it still drops me out with the exactly same error

Comment: @ДмитрийД what? `int situation` and `userInput("souls");`??